# index match in SQL

Tags: sql

Sorry in advance. I am very new in SQL. I don't know how to do a simple task like excel index match equivalent in SQL.

I have 2 tables in SQL (Please ignore the dash, I was using it to align the columns)

**Table1**

```
| Name   | Limit1 || Limit2 |
| First  | A      || 05     | 
| Second | B      || 10     |
| Third  |        || 10     |
```

**Table2**

```
| Limit1Key|| Limit1Value    || Limit2Key   ||Limit2Value|
| A        || 20,000         || 02          ||2,000,000  |
| B        || 50,000         || 05          ||5,000,000  |
|          ||                || 10          ||10,000,000 |
```

I want to get a final table looking like below.

**Result Table**

```
| Name    || Limit1   || Limit2      |
| First   || 20,000   || 5,000,000   | 
| Second  || 50,000   || 10,000,000  |
| Third   ||          || 10,000,000  |
```

If there is already another post similar to this, please guide me to it.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you just want two joins:

```
select t1.*, t2_1.limit1value, t2_2.limit2_value
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2_1
     on t2_1.limit1key = t1.limit1 left join
     table2 t2_2
     on t2_2.limit2key = t1.limit2;
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand now. By joining the second time, i have to join the 2nd table with the new name

Comment: @SQLROOKIE . . . Exactly.  The "name" is called a *table alias* in SQL.